# How to forward declare inherited class in generator function with different files?

Tags: c++

Hi I'm having issues refactoring code. I currently have a `message.cpp` file which currently defines a litany of different inherited message types. I wanted to add a new inherited class, which differs from these existing messages in that it does not participate in a consensus protocol, but rather some utility purpose. So that's where the refactoring comes in.

Here's a simplied version of the original files with all the message types omitted besides the one I'm creating.

`Message.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef _MESSAGE_H_
#define _MESSAGE_H_


enum RemReqType
{
    SCAN_MSG
};


class Message
{
public:
    static Message *create_message(RemReqType rtype);
    static void release_message(Message *msg);
    RemReqType rtype;
};


class ScanMessage : public Message
{
public:
    
};


#endif
```

`Message.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "message.h"


Message *Message::create_message(RemReqType rtype)
{
    Message *msg;
    switch (rtype)
    {
    case SCAN_MSG:
        msg = new ScanMessage;
        std::cout << "SCAN_MSG Message Created" << std::endl; 
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "FALSE TYPE: " << rtype << "\n";
        fflush(stdout);
        assert(false);
    }
    assert(msg);
    msg->rtype = rtype;
    
    return msg;
}


void Message::release_message(Message *msg)
{
    switch (msg->rtype)
    {
    case SCAN_MSG:
    {
        ScanMessage *m_msg = (ScanMessage *)msg;
        std::cout << "SCAN_MSG Message Deleted" << std::endl; 
        delete m_msg;
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        assert(false);
    }
    }
}
```

`main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "message.h"

int main(void) {

    Message *msg = Message::create_message(SCAN_MSG);

    Message::release_message(msg);
    
    return 0;
}
```

[See here for full original code.](https://github.com/resilientdb/resilientdb/blob/master/transport/message.cpp)

Naturally I created another file `utility_message.cpp` to place the inherited class `ScanMessage`.

`utility_message.cpp`:

```cpp
#include "utility_message.h"
```

`utility_message.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef UTILITY_MESSAGE_H_
#define UTILITY_MESSAGE_H_

#include "message.h"

class ScanMessage : public Message
{
public:
    
};

#endif
```

`Message.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef _MESSAGE_H_
#define _MESSAGE_H_


enum RemReqType
{
    SCAN_MSG
};


class Message
{
public:
    static Message *create_message(RemReqType rtype);
    static void release_message(Message *msg);
    RemReqType rtype;
};

#endif
```

`Message.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "message.h"


Message *Message::create_message(RemReqType rtype)
{
    Message *msg;
    switch (rtype)
    {
    case SCAN_MSG:
        msg = new ScanMessage;
        std::cout << "SCAN_MSG Message Created" << std::endl; 
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "FALSE TYPE: " << rtype << "\n";
        fflush(stdout);
        assert(false);
    }
    assert(msg);
    msg->rtype = rtype;
    
    return msg;
}


void Message::release_message(Message *msg)
{
    switch (msg->rtype)
    {
    case SCAN_MSG:
    {
        ScanMessage *m_msg = (ScanMessage *)msg;
        std::cout << "SCAN_MSG Message Deleted" << std::endl; 
        delete m_msg;
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        assert(false);
    }
    }
}
```

This is where my problems begin because I cannot compile.

```
message.cpp: In static member function ‘static Message* Message::create_message(RemReqType)’:
message.cpp:13:19: error: ‘ScanMessage’ does not name a type; did you mean ‘Message’?
   13 |         msg = new ScanMessage;
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   Message
message.cpp: In static member function ‘static void Message::release_message(Message*)’:
message.cpp:34:9: error: ‘ScanMessage’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘Message’?
   34 |         ScanMessage *m_msg = (ScanMessage *)msg;
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~
      |         Message
message.cpp:34:22: error: ‘m_msg’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘msg’?
   34 |         ScanMessage *m_msg = (ScanMessage *)msg;
      |                      ^~~~~
      |                      msg
message.cpp:34:44: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
   34 |         ScanMessage *m_msg = (ScanMessage *)msg;
      |                                            ^
message.cpp:36:16: error: type ‘<type error>’ argument given to ‘delete’, expected pointer
   36 |         delete m_msg;
```

When I add a forward declaration in my `message.h` to so that the type can be deduced I get this error instead:

```
message.cpp: In static member function ‘static Message* Message::create_message(RemReqType)’:
message.cpp:13:19: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class ScanMessage’
   13 |         msg = new ScanMessage;
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from message.cpp:4:
message.h:7:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class ScanMessage’
    7 | class ScanMessage;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
message.cpp: In static member function ‘static void Message::release_message(Message*)’:
message.cpp:36:16: warning: possible problem detected in invocation of delete operator: [-Wdelete-incomplete]
   36 |         delete m_msg;
      |                ^~~~~
message.cpp:34:22: warning: ‘m_msg’ has incomplete type
   34 |         ScanMessage *m_msg = (ScanMessage *)msg;
      |                      ^~~~~
In file included from message.cpp:4:
message.h:7:7: note: forward declaration of ‘class ScanMessage’
    7 | class ScanMessage;
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~
message.cpp:36:16: note: neither the destructor nor the class-specific operator delete will be called, even if they are declared when the class is defined
   36 |         delete m_msg;
      |                ^~~~~
make: *** [<builtin>: message.o] Error 1
```

Please let me know how I can allow this generator function in the `Message` class to produce my new inherited class. Or, if we've been following a bad design pattern please give me advise. Thanks again for the many help!

Comment: You appear to have a circular dependency between `Message` and `ScanMessage`.  It would help if you added the code for `message.cpp` to your question (the code behind the link does not appear to correspond to the error messages in the question, and it should not be behind a link anyhow).

Comment: @PaulSanders Thank you for the suggestion. I went ahead and provided you the code I'm working with. How should I deal with circular dependancy, I tried doing a forward declaration however I get ```transport/message.cpp:102:13: error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class ScanMessage’
   msg = new ScanMessage;```

Comment: I don't see the code in your question.  You need to add it there.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Updated!

Comment: Thank you everyone for walking me through this! I imagined it'd be more helpful to provide all the code but after giving a simpler example I understand the suggestions. Let me know if theres something I missed. Thanks~

Comment: MRE aside, wouldn't a virtual destructor help here? Passing around pointer to the base class with non-virtual d-tor seems unsafe enough...

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thanks for the suggestion, I've since updated my question to reflect your earlier advice for me to have a minimal reproducible example. If there's still an issue let me know and I'll go and correct it. Thanks again.

Comment: @AlejandroArmas Great! The question is much clearer now. I'll look at it in about 10 hours if noone has answered by then.

Comment: @TedLyngmo Thank you. I came up with a solution of creating a seperate factory class, however it involves rewriting/redesigning *a lot* of code and have been hesitant to move forward and do that outside of this simple example.

Comment: @AlejandroArmas Did you try my solution that doesn't require rewriting/redesigning anything?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have duplicates of the files in your question. I used the files at the bottom of the question.

To fix the problems, I only had to add

```
#include "utility_message.h"
```

to `message.cpp`, making it:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "message.h"
#include "utility_message.h"


Message *Message::create_message(RemReqType rtype)
{
    Message *msg;
    switch (rtype)
    {
    case SCAN_MSG:
        msg = new ScanMessage;
        std::cout << "SCAN_MSG Message Created" << std::endl;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "FALSE TYPE: " << rtype << "\n";
        fflush(stdout);
        assert(false);
    }
    assert(msg);
    msg->rtype = rtype;

    return msg;
}


void Message::release_message(Message *msg)
{
    switch (msg->rtype)
    {
    case SCAN_MSG:
    {
        ScanMessage *m_msg = (ScanMessage *)msg;
        std::cout << "SCAN_MSG Message Deleted" << std::endl;
        delete m_msg;
        break;
    }
    default:
    {
        assert(false);
    }
    }
}
```

```
$ g++ -o main main.cpp message.cpp utility_message.cpp -Wall -Wextra -pedantic \
      -pedantic-errors -g -fsanitize=address,undefined
$ ./main
SCAN_MSG Message Created
SCAN_MSG Message Deleted
```